# pandas.DataFrame.shift() fill_value not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This may sound like a rather weird question, but when I'm using the `pandas.DataFrame.shift()` function with the `fill_value` keyword argument, I keep getting a `TypeError: shift() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'`.

Even a simple example on the documentation is giving me that error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'c2': [4, 5, 6],
                   'c3': [7, 8, 9]})

df.shift(periods=1, fill_value=0)
```

Would normally expected

```
    c1    c2    c3
0   0     0     0
1   1     4     7
2   2     5     8
3   3     6     9
```

but it throws the error. Would anybody happen to know what the problem may be? I've searched elsewhere but it seems that nobody else is experiencing this problem...

Comment: for me it works fine though, only last row get eliminated..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is use pandas bellow `0.24+` where is not imlemented this parameter in [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

> **fill_value** : object, optional
>
> The scalar value to use for newly introduced missing values. the default depends on the dtype of self. For numeric data, np.nan is used. For datetime, timedelta, or period data, etc. NaT is used. For extension dtypes, self.dtype.na_value is used.
>
> Changed in version **0.24.0**.

Then use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.shift(periods=1).fillna(0)
```

Or [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with specify first row by position by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) if possible another missing values in data and necessary replace only it:

```
df = df.shift(periods=1)
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].fillna(0)
print (df)
    c1   c2   c3
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  4.0  7.0
2  2.0  5.0  8.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was skeptical that it was a version problem because I thought I had upgrade my Pandas package a few days ago but I guess not. It's good to know the other ways to fill in the values with lower version though. :)