# How to create a new column in dataframe, which will be a function of other columns and conditionals without iteratng over the rows with a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a relatively large data frame (8737 rows and 16 columns of all variable types, strings, integers, booleans etc.) and I want to create a new column based on an equation and some conditionals. Basically, I want to iterate over one particular column, take its values and after multiplications, sums etc. create a new value which then I check if it satisfies some conditions (>= or < to a set value). If it satisfies the conditionals then I need to keep the output of the calculation, else assign a fixed value.

I am doing that by looping over the entire dataset with a for loop, which takes a huge amount of time. I am quite new to python and couldn't quite find any similar problem solution online, other than alternating existing columns without a for loop.

Lets say for the sake of simplicity I have this data frame called df_test:

```
          A         B         C          D    S
0  0.001568  0.321316 -0.269841   3.232037  5.0
1  1.926186 -1.111863 -0.387165   5.541699  NaN
2  2.110923 -0.403940 -0.029895  -9.688968  NaN
3  0.609391  1.697205 -1.827488  -1.273713  NaN
4 -0.577739  0.394475 -1.524400  16.505185  NaN
5  0.456884 -1.238733  0.453586  -4.868735  NaN
```

where S is the column I need to calculate, starting from a set value. 
Next value of S I need to be the previous value of S plus some calculation like so:

```
df_test.S[1]=df_test.S[0]+df_test.D[1]*abs(df_test.C[1])*0.5
```

Then this value should be evaluated by a conditional. If it is larger than equal to, for example 10, then assign 10 to it (instead of the calculation) and if its less or equal to 5 then assign 5 to it.

I use a for loop over the data set and for every element I run the equation that I need. Basically it works like this:

```
for i in range (1,df_test.shape[0]):
    df_test.S[i]=df_test.S[i-1]+df_test.D[i]*abs(df_test.C[i])*0.5
    if df_test.S[i]<5:
        df_test.S[i]=5
    elif df_test.S[i]>10:
        df_test.S[i]=10
```

This code for 8737 rows takes around 20 mins to complete.

If you need any clarifications, please ask me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say the previous value, do you mean, the calculated previous value or the initial previous value?

Comment: Previous calculated value. The initial value is there to get started with the first calculation which, also in reality, is not zero but a fixed value.

Comment: Can you provide code to reproduce your dataframe? also the expected output dataframe

Comment: Well, I just made a random data frame for the sake of the example like this:
```
df_test=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_test.D=df_test.D*10
df_test['S']=np.nan
df_test['S'][0]=5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that really easily in two steps:

```py
df.loc[1:, 'S'] = df.loc[1:, "D"] * 0.5 * df.loc[1:, "C"].abs()  # Computes the numerical expression you want
df["S"] = df["S"].cumsum() # Add the previous to the current item of S


# Then compute your `if` condition
df.loc[df["S"] < 5, 'S'] = 5
df.loc[df["S"] > 10, 'S'] = 10
```

==> no `for` loop.

Comment: But this changes the first value of S too

Comment: @MohitMotwani which part? `cumsum()` doesn't change the first value of `df["S"]`

Comment: Not the cumsum(), the df.D * df.C changes the value of the first row

Comment: You are correct, I missed the part where OP said the `5` value was instanced. I'll edit my post to suggest a simple fix.

Comment: I have made the changes. Please check.

Comment: I don't think this works because you are computing the S column, cumsum-ing it and then you check for the conditional. My intention is to check the conditional immediately after the calculation is made (numerical calculation and sum with previous value) so that the next "itteration" can take either the previous calculated value or, if it didn't meet the conditions, the assigned value. Does it makes sense? @ggrelet

Comment: Hi again @ChronisChochlidakis, could you try the following:
```python
df.loc[0:, 'S'] = (df.loc[0:, 'S'].reset_index(drop=True) + df.loc[1:, "D"].reset_index(drop=True) * 0.5 * df.loc[1:, "C"].reset_index(drop=True).abs()).cumsum().clip(5, 10).shift(1, fill_value=5)
```
If that suits you I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hello @ggrelet. I'm having this error message: 
TypeError: shift() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'

Comment: Which version of pandas / python are you using? I'm using [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and `fill_value` is a parameter of that function. (PS: I edited an index in my formula)

Comment: Ok check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662644/pandas-dataframe-shift-fill-value-not-working there is a workaround.

Comment: pandas version 0.23.4 / python version 3.7. I am scripitng in spyder by the way, I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: `df.loc[0:, 'S'] = (df.loc[0:, 'S'].reset_index(drop=True) + df.loc[1:, "D"].reset_index(drop=True) * 0.5 * df.loc[1:, "C"].reset_index(drop=True).abs()).cumsum().clip(5, 10).shift(1).fillna(0)` should do it, then.

Comment: In a different randomly generated dataframe (in the same manner as the example df I have) it doesn't work. It gives the same result as if the conditionals are checked after the initial calculations and cumsum has been made :/

Comment: Could you share your expected result if your matrix is only made of number`2`? ```df=pd.DataFrame(np.full((6, 4), 2), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.loc[0, "S"] = 5
df = df.fillna(0)```

Comment: sure.
`Out[57]: 
   A  B  C  D     S
0  2  2  2  2   5.0
1  2  2  2  2   7.0
2  2  2  2  2   9.0
3  2  2  2  2  10.0
4  2  2  2  2  10.0
5  2  2  2  2  10.0`
Although I dont think this matrix is such a good example as it increases every time the value of S until it caps at 10

Comment: If you take a look at my for loop, you will understand how I need the previous value to be incorporated to the calculation of the next value and the checked (from the conditionals) before proceeding to the next calculation. If the calculation of the i-th value is, i.e 4, directly affects the value of the i+1 element as it will be value of i+1 = 5 + calculations... instead of 4+calculations. That is why I need to check the value after each calculation for each element. Hope I make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This (untested) & not sure what you want with values between 5 to 10

```py
df_test['S'].iloc[0] = 5
df_test['S'] = df_test['S'].shift() + df_test['D'] * abs(df_test['C'])*0.5
df_test['S'] = np.where(df_test['S'] < 5, 5, df_test['S'])
df_test['S'] = np.where(df_test['S'] > 10, 10, df_test['S'])
```

Comment: Here you are calculating the S column as a first step, and then checking for the conditional. I want to do that in one step so after each "itteration" the previous value added to the current one should be either the numerical calculated value or, if it didnt meet the conditions, the assigned value. In other words, if the previous value is 4.8 then set it to 5 and use 5 to be the previous value to the next calculation instead of 4.8. Does that make sense? @tvgriek

Answer (score 0):

If your transformation would not have an if-condition it could be treated with
[`scipy.signal.lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html)

At first we calculate the exogenous part

`exo = 0.5 * df['D'].multiply(df['C'].abs())`

After that we use `lfilter`

```
start = df['S'].iloc[0]
s = lfilter(np.array([1]), np.array([1, -1]), exo.shift(-1), zi=np.array([start]))[0]
df['S'].iloc[1:] = s[:-1]
```

On my computer this is about 70 times faster than the loop solution.

But sadly it won't help you because of the missing if-condition

Comment: Unfortunately it does have the if condition, but thank you for the effort :)

Answer (score -1):

You can directly add-substract columns from others in pandas. e.g.

```
df['S'] = df.A + df.B - df.C + df.apply(abs)**2
```

If you want to change some value wrt to a condition use **.loc**
Usage:

```
>>>df.loc[coniditon(row), (column value to be changed)] = value
>>>df.loc[df.S < 5, 'S'] = 5
>>>df.loc[df.S > 10, 'S'] = 10
```

And use cumulative summation function .cumsum() on row "S" to add values before to after.

```
df['S'] = df.S.cumsum()
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants

Comment: This way I am affecting the calculation result which I don't want. If, for example the calculation is less than 5 and I assign 5 to it, then I need this 5 value to be the previous value for the next value calculation. If I do all the calculations and afterwards checking for the conditionals, I am changing the result