# How to create a new column in dataframe, which will be a function of another column and conditionals faster than a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a relatively large data frame (8737 rows and 16 columns of all variable types, strings, integers, booleans etc.) and I want to create a new column based on an equation and some conditionals. Basically, I want to iterate over one particular column, take its values and after an operation calculate a value. Then I need to check if this value satisfies some conditions (>= or < to a set value). If it satisfies the conditionals then I need to keep the output of the calculation as an element of the new column, else assign a fixed value to that element.

I am doing that by looping over the entire dataset with a for loop, which takes a huge amount of time. I am quite new to python and couldn't quite find any similar problem solution online, other than alternating existing columns without a for loop.

Lets say for the sake of simplicity I have this data frame called df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['A']=[5,3,7,4,3,0,1,7,8,10,9,4,3,2,0]
df['S']=np.nan
df['S'][0]=5

Out[4]: 
     A    S
0    5  5.0
1    3  NaN
2    7  NaN
3    4  NaN
4    3  NaN
5    0  NaN
6    1  NaN
7    7  NaN
8    8  NaN
9   10  NaN
10   9  NaN
11   4  NaN
12   3  NaN
13   2  NaN
14   0  NaN
```

where S is the new column I need to calculate, starting from a set value. Next value of S I need to be the previous value of S plus some calculation. Basically, for every step of the calculation I want **S(i)=S(i-1)+A(i)x0.5-2*** and right after this to check ***if S(i)=<5 then S(i)=5, elseif S(i)>=10 then S(i)=10***. This is one step of the itteration. My code is this with the desired outcome:

```
for i in range (1,df.shape[0]):
    df.S[i]=df.S[i-1]+df.A[i]*0.5-2
    if df.S[i]<=5:
        df.S[i]=5
    elif df.S[i]>10:
        df.S[i]=10
df

Out[6]: 
     A     S
0    5   5.0
1    3   5.0
2    7   6.5
3    4   6.5
4    3   6.0
5    0   5.0
6    1   5.0
7    7   6.5
8    8   8.5
9   10  10.0
10   9  10.0
11   4  10.0
12   3   9.5
13   2   8.5
14   0   6.5
```

This code for 8737 rows takes around 20 mins to complete. Is there any way to do this without a for loop or with a different, faster itterative method? 
If you need any clarifications, please ask me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new column in dataframe, which will be a function of other columns and conditionals without iteratng over the rows with a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55724579/how-to-create-a-new-column-in-dataframe-which-will-be-a-function-of-other-colum)

Comment: It actually is, a simpler form of the problem, trying to get an answer. I  couldn't just delete my old question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `numba` for optimalize it:

```
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def get_vals(a, first):
    out = np.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype=float)
    out[0] = first
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        out[i] = out[i-1] + a[i]*0.5-2
        out[i] = 5 if out[i]<=5 else out[i]
        out[i] = 10 if out[i] > 10 else out[i]
    return out

arr = df['A'].values
df['new'] = get_vals(arr, df.loc[0, 'S'])
```

Comment: Hello @jezrael. I get this error when running your code:

`TypingError: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function zeros>) with argument(s) of type(s): (int64, dtype=Function(<class 'float'>))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in function zeros>)
[2] During: typing of call at <ipython-input-7-c5ca1593ebc5> (4)`

Comment: I replaced `np.zeros` with `np.ones` and it worked! 
I think it works with this method! Thank you so much @jezrael!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this you're looking for. I think you can use .apply for this case. For example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['A']=[5,3,7,4,3,0,1,7,8,10,9,4,3,2,0]
df['S']=np.nan
df['S'][0]=5

def cal(i):
    return i**2

df['S'] = df['A'].apply(cal)

display(df)
```

It will assign new values on 'S' based on the calculation

Comment: Hello there. This does not incorporate the if statements (the "check" of the value after each iteration) than I am looking for.