# Mixing raw- and column-wise calcuations in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks similar to this example

| V1 | V2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3.8 | 10 | Result1 |
| 10.7 | 10 | Result2 |
| 19.5 | 10 | Result3 |

The calculation for Result3 would be

```
Result3: (19.5-10.7)*10/2
Result2: (10.7-3.8)*10/2
Result1: (3.8-0)*10/2
```

I know of methods to add values across rows but not mixing raw- and column-wise calculations. And there is this problem with `-0` in the `Result1` as well I cannot come up with a solution.

Would be great if anyone could help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['calculation']=df['V1'].sub(df['V1'].shift(fill_value=0)).mul(10).div(2)
#OR
df['calculation']=((df['V1']-df['V1'].shift(fill_value=0))*10)/2
```

output of df:

```
    V1      V2  Result  calculation
0   3.8     10  Result1     19.0
1   10.7    10  Result2     34.5
2   19.5    10  Result3     44.0
```

### Update:

following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662644/pandas-dataframe-shift-fill-value-not-working):

use:

```
df['calculation']=df['V1'].sub(df['V1'].shift().fillna(0)).mul(10).div(2)
#OR
df['calculation']=((df['V1']-df['V1'].shift().fillna(0))*10)/2
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. With both lines I get the error: shift() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value' in Jupiter Notebook. Do yo have an idea why?

Comment: @ruedi what is your pandas version?

Comment: found the solution! I changed it to .shift().fillna(0) according to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662644/pandas-dataframe-shift-fill-value-not-working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ruedi...updated answer.....kindly have a look **:)**